# Quickblox Push Notifications are delayed

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, quickblox

We use push notifications in our app. They work, but there's some variable delivery delay (sometimes ~10seconds, sometimes more than minute). 
Does anybody know what to do to minimize those delays?
I know APNS has some delay, but I've never experienced such slow deliveries.

**EDIT:**
I digged out some time delay between message sent date and push created date.
I have message sent at 12:40:17 (according to QB's admin panel)
and push notification log for the same message says the the push is: `"created_at":"2016-05-12T12:40:28Z"`
Clearly we have 11 seconds difference between the time message is sent to QB and push notification being sent to APNS from QB

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications are unreliable and cannot be guaranteed that they have been delivered. It all depends on the apple APNS server, that said, usually when I send a push notification I get the result in under a few seconds.

They are not reliable! ****There is no guarantee that push notifications will actually be delivered, even if the APNS server accepted them****.

**As far as your server is concerned, push notifications are fire-and-forget; there is no way to find out what the status of a notification is after you’ve sent it to APNS.** The delivery time may also vary, from seconds up to half an hour.

Also, the user’s iPhone may not be able to receive push notifications all the time. They could be on a WiFi network that does not allow connections to be made to APNS because the required ports are blocked. Or the phone could be turned off.

APNS will try to deliver the last notification it received for that device when it comes back online, but it will only try for a limited time. Once it times out, the push notification will be lost forever!

Comment: I'm sorry but you are talking about pushes in general. The question is about QuicBlox's push notifications.
I know pushes take some time to be delivered and there's no guarantee of that. See my edited question for further details.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I am running into this issue too with Quickblox. The push notifications, a critical part of the communication flow, are delayed by up to a minute or so. I use push all the time in enterprise apps and yes, they should not be considered reliable, but in practice APNS communications are remarkably reliable and near instantaneous in my experience. It seems like Quickblox is queuing (throttling?) notification requests, my guess is to conserve bandwidth - aren't they based in Russia? It's spoiling what would otherwise be a great product.